# How to decode the output of seq2seq?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, deep-learning, machine-translation

The code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/translate.py#L281) of the Tensorflow translate.py example confused me. The copied code is:

```
  # This is a greedy decoder - outputs are just argmaxes of output_logits.
  outputs = [int(np.argmax(logit, axis=1)) for logit in output_logits]
```

Why does the `argmax` work?

The `output_logits`'s shape is `[bucket_length,batch_size,embedding_size]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each logit (or: activation for each word) they take the index where the activation has the highest value of everything.

For the argmax: take a look at the numpy examples on this page: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

```
a = array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.argmax(a)
5
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=0)
array([1, 1, 1])
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=1)
array([2, 2])
```

So what output does is:

- For each word (the length of bucket_length)

  - get the max activation of the embedding_size

You should look at the shape of the resulting outputs array. You will see that because batch_size is 1 it all works out!

Let me know if this helps you!

Comment: Thank you. But my question is mainly about why argmax could result in  the translated word id.

Comment: Does the numpy example help?

Comment: Thank you. I know what argmax means.

Comment: So did this answer your question? Or are you unclear about how you get the output_logits?

Comment: No. The model want to translate. So my question is how the output_logits could be transfered to word id in vocabulary.

Comment: The output size of the output_logits should be equal to the `to_vocab_size`, can you confirm this?

Comment: Great! Can you edit your question, and edit my comment to answer your question for future references?

Comment: Thank you . How do you know the shape of to_vocab_size equal to the shape of output_logits?

Comment: The neural network gives you an activation for each of the words in your output vocabulary. Try to read up on what neural machine translation actually does.

Comment: But I run the program [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/translate.py#L293) and find the output_logits's shape.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-you-provide-some-good-example-of-seq2seq-decoder